# Character string declaration with static size

Tags: c, string, declaration

I was trying different ways to declare a string in C for exam preparation. We know that string in C is character array with `'\0'` at end. Then I found that even if I declare an array of 5 characters and put 5 characters in it like "abcde" it is accepted. Then where is the null char stored?

I declared strings in following ways

```
char str[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char str2[] = "abcde";
char str3[5] = "abcde";
```

Now, in the 3rd case, I am allocating 5 byte of space and I have exactly 5 characters in the array, then if string should have a null character at end where is it being stored? Or is it the case that null is not appended? 
What about the 1st and 2nd cases, are null appended there?
`strlen()` returns 5 in all 3 cases.

Comment: Maybe consider another case: `char str4[] = "abc\0\0";`.  `sizeof(str4)` --> 6 and `strlen(str4)` --> 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third case, the null terminator is not appended. From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization):

> If the size of the array is known, it may be one less than the size of
>   the string literal, in which case the terminating null character is
>   ignored:

So when you check its length with `strlen`, you get undefined behavior (and the the same when you try it with the first one, since that also isn't a string).

Any less that that is not allowed, (for me on MSVC it shows an error but still compiles it, for some reason). More than the string length is allowed, in which case the rest is zero-initialized.

Comment: @Blaze Thanks. Just wanted to know, undefined behavior in ```strlen()``` as in it will return the length of actual string literal?

Comment: @KushalMondal it's undefined behavior in `strlen` because that's its contract, the pointer passed must be a valid null-terminated string. `strlen` just keeps reading until it finds a null-terminator, so if there's none in where it allowed to read, it might cause an access violation or something similar. For instance the result I got in your third case was `21`.

Comment: The first case is also not a _string_.

Comment: @chux good point, I added that to the answer, as it previously may not have been obvious why it's undefined behavior with the first case.

Answer (score 6):

The `NUL` character is stored only in the second example

```
char str2[] = "abcde";
```

where the array is sized automatically to include it. An array of characters does not *have* to be a string, and the other two are encoded without the `NUL` terminator.

If the code happens to treat them correctly as strings, that was an unfortunate result of *undefined behaviour*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char str2[] = "abcde";
    char str3[5] = "abcde";
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof str);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof str2);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof str3);
}
```

Program output:

```
5
6
5
```